# Which vim plugin should I use if i want to surround specific text with brackets like this?

Tags: plugin-system

I just want to transform

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);
}
```

as little key I should press as possible.

I found the plugin 'surround' but It seems like it has some functions(like 'yss{') that surrounds entire text line with brackets but not the block I want to surround. And if it is possible, i have to add some new lines at some position, so i think it will be so uncomfortable.

And I also found some original vim commands, but I was too long and seems like taking too much time.

I'll be so glad if you guys tell me which plugin i should use. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *surround* plugin does actually support this:
If your cursor is in the `i` of the `if`, pressing `yS${` or `ySf;{` will have the desired effect.

In general, substituting an uppercase `S` for the lowercase `s` in most of the plugin's shortcuts will do a linewise operation instead of the default characterwise one.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. You are so genius

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite surprised *surround* plugin doesn't handle this. If it's not there by default, I'm quite certain though that it can be configured to behave this way.

Any way, in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), with the default settings, you can select (in visual mode) from `if` to the semi-colon and hit your leader key (backspace by default) followed by `{`.[image]

In the screencast, `<space>` is my leader key, and `ctrl+alt+4` relates to `{` on my French keyboard.

But honestly, if this is some C++ code, you'd better configure clang-format to your liking and run it on the current line that you would select. This way braces would also be added around the *true* path.

Comment: Besides `lh-brackets` and `surround` (`S` in visual mode, or with more advanced config), the plugin [splitjoin.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) is designed to handle this exact case (in many languages)

Comment: After i install and add 'LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib' and 'LucHermitte/lh-brackets'
when i paste code 
'for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);'  from my clipboard, It became 
'for(int i = 1); i <= N; i++) if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);'
but if i commentize those plugins, there are no problems. What should i do?

Comment: @davidHwang That's odd. Whether I paste in normal mode, or in insert mode (with mouse middle button, or with `i_CTRL-R_+`/`p`) I don't observe anything like that. What you observe looks more like if you have typed the text manually -- I've configured the semi colon to close all opened parenthesis, and sometimes its behaviour can become quite annoying even with the abbreviations/Snippets I define in lh-cpp. How do you paste? And what `:set` tells you? Note: it'll may be best to continue this discussion either by mail or though an issue that you could open.

Comment: @LucHermitte while trying to help out @davidHwang with his [other question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13754/14380) I was able to reproduce the issue. I was pasting from the clipboard with <C-V> while in insert mode (the ubuntu bash terminal equivalent of <C-v>. I believe invoking such a paste does indeed behave as if it were pasting each char manually. Ie if I am in normal mode the text would have only pasted 
`nt i = 1); i <= N; i++) if(ord[i] == -1) dfs(i, 0, i);` as it wouldnt be in insert mode till an i is pasted

Comment: @ljden. Thanks for the explanation. I'll have to improve context analysis in `;` mapping.